# How search in repository by IDENTITY in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some table in Symfony app

```
id
user_id
test_id
type_id
points
```

I need search by different pairs: user_id and test_id, user_id and type_id, test_id and type_id.
I can write methods in repository, like this for all pairs:

```
$hints = $this->createQueryBuilder('points')
            ->andWhere('IDENTITY(points.user) = :user_id')
            ->andWhere('IDENTITY(points.test) = :test_id')
            ->setParameters([
                'user_id' => $user->getId(),
                'test_id' => $test->getId(),
            ])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

But I want not to add each time new function in repository for new combination and execute searching by standard methods like `$repository->findBy(['IDENTITY(points.user)' => 1])` or `$repository->matching($creteria)`.
But in this way I get error `Unrecognized field: IDENTITY(points.user)`

How search by standard functions with IDENTITY?

Comment: it's normal for you to make that mistake. `IDENTITY(points.user)` is not a field of your entity
have you tried `findby(['user' => yourUserEntity, 'test' => yourTestEntity])`?

Comment: @Skyd I've tried this way and it works! With id like `$pointsRep->findBy(['user' => 1]);` and by entity `$pointsRep->findBy(['user' => $user]);`. Thanks. Now I not really understand why IDENTITY keyword is exist if we can search by this methods.

Comment: Perfect ! Personally, I didn't know IDENTITY keywords. ^^' 
I've always used this method for this kind of standard search. And SensioLabs trainers never told me about this type of research.
By the way. Have fun

Answer (score -1):

As Skyd said in comments it could be executed by `$pointsRep->findBy(['user' => 1]);` or by `$pointsRep->findBy(['user' => $user]);`